# Grid for atlas plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, print-composer, qgis-3, atlas

Any alternative for the plugin Grids for Atlas in Qgis 3?. I use it a lot because I always create atlas in my works but currently I have to create the coverage layer in qgis 2.18 and the continue my work in Qgis3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to use this tool too (though not for a while).  I recently had the same issue and came up with the following work flow:

1. Go `Vector->Research Tools->Create grid` (choose polygon for the output)
2. Set your extent by selecting 'Use layer extent' from the button on the right and choose the layer of interest as you would in the old plugin.
3. Choose a size for each map coverage (horizontal and vertical spacing - use the measure tool to get an idea or set up a test map in print composer so it looks right and measure from that (using the 'view extent in map canvas).
4. Optionally set an overlap between the grids.

You will now have a set of polygon features in a regular grid and this will match one of the functions of the plugin exactly.

To get an irregular set, optimally overlaid (so minimising the pages in the atlas), you will need to edit the polygons.  Manual editing sounds cumbersome, but I usually had to tweak the output from the plugin anyway, so it doesn't make much difference.

To edit the position of the polygons, turn on editing for your grid layer and use the `Move feature(s)` tool in the `Advanced Editing Toolbar`.  This lets you click on a polygon and then drag the entire feature to a new location (no need to even select in the conventional way).  With a grid of half a dozen features (6 maps in Atlas), it takes only moments to organise them optimally.

Answer (score 0):

Look what I found: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/coveragebuilder/#plugin-about

if you want to plugin to be visible from the plugin manager in QGIS, you must select the "experimental" in plugins settings